# Parse this Json array and extract the value of text

Tags: arrays, json, parsing

Here is the full json that I want to parse and extract the `text` that has the value: `The product is in second line 3rd row`.

Can someone help?

```
"activities": [                                             
    {                                                         
      "type": "message",                                      
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",               
      "timestamp": "2019-07-01T15:18:56.8251462Z",            
      "serviceUrl": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",   
      "channelId": "directline",                              
      "from": {                                               
        "id": "user1"                                         
      },                                                      
      "conversation": {                                       
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"                      
      },                                                      
      "text": "the milk"                                      
    },                                                        
    {                                                         
      "type": "message",                                      
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",               
      "timestamp": "2019-07-01T15:18:57.6856172Z",            
      "localTimestamp": "2019-07-01T15:18:57.5099359+00:00",  
      "channelId": "directline",                              
      "from": {                                               
        "id": "XXXXXX",                                        
        "name": "XXXXXX"                                       
      },                                                      
      "conversation": {                                       
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"                      
      },                                                      
      "text": "The product is in second line 3rd row",        
      "attachments": [],                                      
      "entities": [],                                         
      "replyToId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"         
    }                                                         
  ],                                                          
  "watermark": "1"                                            
}
```

Comment: Using what language/tech ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have specified that this is a full json you have placed in the question, But it is not full json you are missing something.

```
"activities": 
   [     //json array start from here                                          
    {                                                         
      "type": "message",                                      
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",               
      "timestamp": "2019-07-01T15:18:56.8251462Z",            
      "serviceUrl": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",   
      "channelId": "directline",                              
      "from": {                                               
        "id": "user1"                                         
      },                                                      
      "conversation": {                                       
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"                      
      },                                                      
      "text": "the milk"                                      
    },                                                        
    {                                                         
      "type": "message",                                      
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",               
      "timestamp": "2019-07-01T15:18:57.6856172Z",            
      "localTimestamp": "2019-07-01T15:18:57.5099359+00:00",  
      "channelId": "directline",                              
      "from": {                                               
        "id": "XXXXXX",                                        
        "name": "XXXXXX"                                       
      },                                                      
      "conversation": {                                       
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"                      
      },                                                      
      "text": "The product is in second line 3rd row",        
      "attachments": [],                                      
      "entities": [],                                         
      "replyToId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"         
    } 

  ],      //json array ends here



    these are extra lines                                                 
  ***"watermark": "1"                                            
}***
```

if you want to use this array you need to add a '{' in very top line before

**"activities": [**

I am placing here a valid json now you can check it on [Json parser used to parse json in objects](https://jsoneditoronline.org/)

***Valid Json Here : ***

```
{
"activities": [                                             
    {                                                         
      "type": "message",                                      
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",               
      "timestamp": "2019-07-01T15:18:56.8251462Z",            
      "serviceUrl": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",   
      "channelId": "directline",                              
      "from": {                                               
        "id": "user1"                                         
      },                                                      
      "conversation": {                                       
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"                      
      },                                                      
      "text": "the milk"                                      
    },                                                        
    {                                                         
      "type": "message",                                      
      "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",               
      "timestamp": "2019-07-01T15:18:57.6856172Z",            
      "localTimestamp": "2019-07-01T15:18:57.5099359+00:00",  
      "channelId": "directline",                              
      "from": {                                               
        "id": "XXXXXX",                                        
        "name": "XXXXXX"                                       
      },                                                      
      "conversation": {                                       
        "id": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"                      
      },                                                      
      "text": "The product is in second line 3rd row",        
      "attachments": [],                                      
      "entities": [],                                         
      "replyToId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"         
    }                                                         
  ],                                                          
  "watermark": "1"                                            
}
```